# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting in python script output

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am attempting to learn python following using "Learn Python the Hard Way" 3rd edition and getting an error on exercise 8.

I have python v 2.7.11 and using the following code

```
formatter = "%r %r %r $r"

print formatter % (1, 2, 3, 4)
print formatter % ("one", "two", "three", "four")
print formatter % (True, False, False, True)
print formatter % (formatter, formatter, formatter, formatter)
print formatter % (
    "I had this thing.",
    "That you could type up right.",
    "But it didn't sing.",
    "So I said goodnight."
)
```

when running python ex8.py, i get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex8.py", line 3, in <module>
    print formatter % (1, 2, 3, 4)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

what could be the issue in this code? From what I see, this is exactly what is typed in the book, but I am getting the error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Also, any other resources to help learn python would be appreciated.

Comment: It should be `formatter = "%r %r %r %r"` – You wrote `$r` instead of `%r` for the last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what's the `$r` doing?

```
formatter = "%r %r %r %r"
```

should work!

Comment: Thank you so much, not sure how i missed that! Looking at the screen for too long makes you see the same thing over and over again.